# Python expression in Typehints indexer

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, expression, type-hinting

I need to get a Union of many Tuple[] variant.

I trying replace this:

```
MyTypeHint = Union[Tuple[Decimal], Tuple[Decimal, Decimal], Tuple[Decimal, Decimal, Decimal], etc ]
```

By this:

```
MyTipeHint = Union[*[Tuple[*[Decimal]*x]] * x for x in range(1, 10)]
MyTipeHint = Union[*[Tuple[*[Decimal]*x]]* x for x in [10]]
```

But it,s not working. I have syntax error.

Also, I know for ellipsis, but Tuple[Decimal, ...] not working with marshmallow shemas.

Comment: maybe you can use eval() and string multiplication

Comment: what are "marshmallow shemas"?

Comment: marshmallow is an ORM/ODM/framework-agnostic library for converting complex datatypes, such as objects, to and from native Python datatypes.